# Only limit one period/decimal in field (client-side validation) Regex - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, client-side-validation

I have a client-side validation function in JavaScript for a field **Value** that allows the user to enter-in a dollar amount. The validation works perfect (only allows numbers and periods/decimals to be inputted) into the field. All other characters are simply deleted. **I like to update the function where it allows only one decimal/period to be inputted, any more than one will be deleted**

Here is what I have so far:

`` onkeyup="if (!RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d*$/).test(this.value)) { this.value = this.value.replace(RegExp(/[A-Za-z-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:;'<>?,\/]+/).exec(this.value), '').replace(String.fromCharCode(34), '');}" ``

Any help/suggestion would be great!

Comment: have you tried this.value.toFixed(1) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't stuff everything into the HTML event attribute. Write a function! That also removes the necessity to use `String.fromCharCode(34)` just to get a double quote character.

   BTW, if you do need a double quote character inside a HTML attribute just use `&quot;`.
2. `RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d*$/)` is duplicated. Just use `/^\d*\.?\d*$/`, because it is already an regular expression. `RegExp` is used if you want to convert a string into regular expression like this: `RegExp("^\\d*\\.?\\d*$")`.
3. Calling `.exec()` and using it as an argument for `.replace()` makes no sense. `.exec()` returns an array (containing matches), but `.replace()` needs a regular expression (or a string) as it's first parameter. Also you need to add the `g`(lobal) flag to the expression or only the first match will be replaced

   ```
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[A-Za-z-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:;'<>?,\/"]+/g, '');
   ```

   Notice I added the double quote character into the regular expression. However it may be easier just to replace everything that is not a digit or a period:

   ```
   this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
   ```

Deleting additional periods can't be done with regular expression alone (at least not in all current browsers). One way to do it would be to [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string at the periods and then join it back together with just the period between the first and second items:

```
function removeAllButFirstPeriod(string) {
  const split = string.split(".");
  if (split.length === 1) {
    // If the split string contains only one element, then there were no periods in the string
    return split[0];
  } else {
    return split[0] + "." + split.slice(1).join(""); 
  }
}
```

(See also [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join))

End result (the `.test` isn't needed. Just always remove all invalid chars):

```
function removeInvalidNumberChars(element) {
  element.value = removeAllButFirstPeriod(element.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
}
```

with (the `input` event is a better choice than `keydown`)

```html
<input oninput="removeInvalidNumberChars(this)">
```